# mongodb apply sort to lookup results

Tags: mongodb

If I have a `user` and `post` collection

```
{"_id": 1, "name": "User 1"}
{"_id": 2, "name": "User 2"}

{"_id": 1, "title": "Post 1", "userId": 1, "createdAt": ISODate("2017-07-24T04:12:54.255Z")}
{"_id": 2, "title": "Post 2", "userId": 1, "createdAt": ISODate("2017-07-25T04:12:54.255Z")}
{"_id": 3, "title": "Post 1", "userId": 2, "createdAt": ISODate("2017-07-24T04:12:54.255Z")}
```

How can I list all users with their latest post? Would be something like

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "User 1",
  "post": {
    "_id": 2,
    "title": "Post 2",
    "userId": 1,
    "createdAt": ISODate("2017-07-25T04:12:54.255Z")
  }
}
```

I know I can easily use $lookup, $unwind post, then $sort by post.createdAt, but that leave me with redundant user (User 1 will be listed twice for Post 1 and Post 2).

I don't know how can I use $group to remove duplicates while keep maintaining other fields (name, post.title, etc)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I solved the duplicates using $group and $first

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
    {$lookup: {from: "post", localField: "_id", foreignField: "userId", as: "post"}},
    {$unwind: { path: "$post", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    {$sort: {"post.createdAt": -1}},
    {$group: {"_id": "$_id", "name": {$first: "$name"}, "post": {$first: "$post"}},
    {$project: {"_id": 1, "name": 1, "post": 1}}
])
```

Feel free to post your answer

Comment: it works when you do not provide limit. consider if i provide limit of 10 posts and first user in user collection have 12 recent post then ????

Answer (score 36):

You can solve this in a single aggregation step with the new [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) syntax

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([{
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'posts',
      'let': {
        'userId': '$_id'
      },
      'pipeline': [{
          '$match': { '$expr': { '$eq': ['$userId', '$$userId'] } }
        }, {
          '$sort': {  'createdAt': -1 }
        }, {
          '$limit': 10
        },
      ],
      'as': 'posts'
    }
  }
])
```

Note: untested code, but the principle should be clear.

Comment: works perfectly and also shows how to work with the new $lookup syntax. tnx a million!

Comment: You don't need `let` and `pipeline`, simply put the $match, $sort, $limit before $lookup (and include $localField, $foreignField), see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, @netwire, could you share an example?

Comment: The `$sort` operation within the lookup pipeline will not make use of any index. So this might well turn out quite slow.

Answer (score 3):

here is a way you can use

```
db.getCollection('post').aggregate([
{ $limit: 10 },

{$sort: {"createdAt": -1}},

{$lookup: {from: "user", localField: "userId", foreignField: "_id", as: "user"}},
])
```

you should query post which sorted by date and join with user. so if you want to provide a limit for posts then you can.